# Pytest with classes and parameterization

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test that comes with a number of test cases in an [(astropy) table](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/index.html); each test case is in a table row.

Currently, I do it like this:

```
import pytest
from astropy.table import Table

@pytest.mark.parametrize('row', Table.read('testcases.fits'))
def test_cases(row):
    my_limit = 5.0
    assert abs(row['foo'] - row['bar']) < my_limit
```

(When iterating over the table, one gets the rows, which are kind-of dictionaries of the cells. And the test is actually more complicated than shown in the example; I really need each row as an individual test case.)

I need to have this a bit more flexible outside of the tests; namely I need to plot the test cases (for the sphinx-doc documentation). This makes it suitable to create a class instead of individual functions:

```
import pytest
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.table import Table

class MyTest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.testcases = Table.read('testcases.fits')
        self.my_limit = 5.0

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('row', self.testcases)
    def test_cases(self, row):
        assert abs(row['foo'] - row['bar']) < self.my_limit

    def plot(self):
        plt.plot(self.testcases['foo'], self.testcases['bar'])
```

The problem however is that `pytest.mark.parametrize` doesn't know about `self`:

```
E   NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Is there a trick how to use the object attribute within `parametrize`?

Comment: To clarify, you generate the plots as part of running pytest?

Comment: They are generated when the documentation is built. The documentation shall contain a graphical representation of the tests. So, they are tightly bound to the tests, but not run during pytest.

Comment: When the documentation is built, you have non-pytest code which creates instances of `MyTest`, then call `plot`? I’m asking because the way the code looks, pytest will never discover and run the test `test_cases` at all.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea: have some code running with pytest, but re-use parts of it for plotting. Use classes to keep things together.

Comment: Actually, having the test discovered despite of the (required) `__init__()` method is the next question I have.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other things to be addressed before solving the issue with `@pytest.mark.parametrize('row', self.testcases)`. The implementation of how pytest discovers test classes will completely filter out your current implementation from being recognised as a test class:

- [pytest has test class naming conventions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions) which, if not followed or configured, will [skip classes not following the convention](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/2d824329ebf5455aaf4c6f8aa29afff401abe315/src/_pytest/python.py#L242);
- Standard pytest test class discovery [does not allow a custom `__init__` to be defined on the test classes](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/2d824329ebf5455aaf4c6f8aa29afff401abe315/src/_pytest/python.py#L804-L813).

Generally, you'll have to write a [pytest hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/writing_hook_functions.html) in your [`conftest.py`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/writing_plugins.html#conftest-py-plugins) to modify test discovery to get your current implementation to work. A custom implementation of [`pytest_pycollect_makeitem`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_pycollect_makeitem) will probably work (see pytest's [default implementation](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/2d824329ebf5455aaf4c6f8aa29afff401abe315/src/_pytest/python.py#LL236C5-L236C30) to get an idea).

---

In your case, I would reconsider the need for the test case data to be read into instances. If you read the data directly as class variables instead, the issue with both `__init__` and `@parametrize` can be bypassed, as follows:

```py
class MyTest:  # Tweak pytest Test class discovery for this name
    testcases = Table.read('testcases.fits')
    my_limit = 5.0

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('row', testcases)
    def test_cases(self, row):
        assert abs(row['foo'] - row['bar']) < self.my_limit

    def plot(self):
        plt.plot(self.testcases['foo'], self.testcases['bar'])
```

---

**Update**

Due to the way parameterisation works, parameterisation data needs to be defined at module creation time, and there isn't an obvious way to "inherit" parameterisation data and make it work with `@pytest.mark.parametrize` (as far as I know).

If you *really* want to do this, you can use dynamic test generation to achieve something similar.

**I don't condone resorting to this solution**, but here's a minimal implementation **(Requires Python 3.9+)**. First, the desired result (minimal working example):

```py
# test_example.py

class Base:

    testcases: list[int] = []

    @inherit_parametrization
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("num", testcases)
    def test_cases(self, num: int) -> None:
        print("Number is: ", num)

class Test_1(Base):
    testcases = [1, 2]

class Test_2(Base):
    testcases = [3, 4]
```

```
$ pytest test_example.py --verbose -s
platform linux -- Python 3.10.9, pytest-7.2.2, pluggy-1.0.0 --
...
collected 4 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

test_example.py::Test_1::test_cases[1] Number is:  1
PASSED
test_example.py::Test_1::test_cases[2] Number is:  2
PASSED
test_example.py::Test_2::test_cases[3] Number is:  3
PASSED
test_example.py::Test_2::test_cases[4] Number is:  4
PASSED
```

Summary of implementation:

1. Implement a decorator `@inherit_parametrization` which grabs the source code of the thing it's decorating
2. Every time you subclass `Base`, [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) the source code of the decorated object of `@inherit_parametrization`, but using the global namespace of the module `Base` is found in, and the local namespace of the subclass. This allows the `test_cases` function to "see" a new class variable called `testcases` every time you make a subclass.

```py
import collections.abc as cx
import typing as t

import ast
import inspect
import pytest
import sys
import textwrap


TestFuncT = t.TypeVar("TestFuncT", bound=cx.Callable[..., t.Any])


class inherit_parametrization(t.Generic[TestFuncT]):

    func_name: str
    func_src: str
    owning_test_class: type

    def __init__(self, func: TestFuncT, /) -> None:
        src: str = textwrap.dedent(inspect.getsource(func))
        func_stmt: ast.stmt = ast.parse(src).body[0]
        assert isinstance(func_stmt, ast.FunctionDef)
        # Decorators are ordered from top to bottom. Don't include the decorator
        # `@inherit_parametrization` itself when dynamically generating tests.
        func_stmt.decorator_list.pop(0)
        self.func_name = func.__name__
        self.func_src = ast.unparse(func_stmt)

    def __set_name__(self, owner: type, name: str) -> None:
        self.owning_test_class = owner

    def get_parameterized_test(self, current_test_class: type) -> TestFuncT:
        dynamic_namespace: dict[str, object] = dict(current_test_class.__dict__)
        exec(
            self.func_src,
            sys.modules[self.owning_test_class.__module__].__dict__,
            dynamic_namespace,
        )
        return dynamic_namespace[self.func_name]  # type: ignore[return-value]


class Base:

    testcases: list[int] = []

    @inherit_parametrization
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("num", testcases)
    def test_cases(self, num: int) -> None:
        print("Number is: ", num)

    def __init_subclass__(cls) -> None:
        attr_name: str
        for attr_name in dir(cls):
            attr_val: object = getattr(cls, attr_name)
            if isinstance(attr_val, inherit_parametrization):
                setattr(
                    cls,
                    attr_name,
                    attr_val.get_parameterized_test(current_test_class=cls),
                )


class Test_1(Base):
    testcases = [1, 2]


class Test_2(Base):
    testcases = [3, 4]
```

Comment: The problem here is that the class cannot be subclassed: Creating a child class with another file `testcases2.fits` and (and overwritten methods not shown in the simple example) doesn't work, because `pytest.mark.parameterize` always takes `MyTest.testcases` and not the one from the child class.

Comment: @olebole I would consider re-architecting your test suite - I don't believe `@pytest.mark.parametrize` is naturally suited for the way you want to do inheritance. I've updated the answer with a minimal working implementation if you really want to do this, though (but I don't recommend it).

Comment: Thank you for four efforts! This however looks unfortunate as I don't have a good solution yet to organize my "documentable" tests nicely and without code repetition.